# Finding the probability son of Ivy league alumnus attends ...

Tags: probability

In the Dark Ages, $Harvard$, $Dartmouth$, and $Yale$ admitted only
male students.

Assume that, at that time, $80$ percent of the sons of $Harvard$ men went to $Harvard$
and the $rest$ went to $Yale$,

$40$ percent of the sons of $Yale$ men went to $Yale$, and the $rest$ split
evenly between $Harvard$ and $Dartmouth$;

and of the sons of $Dartmouth$ men, $70$ percent went to
$Dartmouth$, $20$ percent to $Harvard$, and $10$ percent to $Yale$.

**Find the probability that the grandson of a man from Harvard went to Harvard.**

From what I can understand,these are dependent of each other. Thus, the chances of the grandson going to Harvard should increase. However, I do not know how to show that in a formula. Can anyone help me with that?

> ANSWER: For this we have to use Markov's Transition Matrix. So as posted below, we must account for all possibilities. Thus:
>   $$P(SHH)P(SHH) + P(SHY)P(SYH) = (.8)(.8) + (.2)(.3) = (.64)+(.06) = .7$$
>   So there is a 70 % chance the grandson of a Harvard man goes to Harvard.

**Modify the above by assuming that the son of a Harvard man always went to
Harvard. Again, find the probability that the grandson of a man from Harvard went to Harvard.**

Would this be just 1? I am assuming that 'always' means that a 100% chance that a son goes to Harvard. Now,if we were to carry this probability down a tree, that 'always' would carry over.

Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix multiplication? Does "Markov chain" mean anything to you? If not, then there are three ways the grandson can reach Harvard: 1) The son went to Harvard 2) The son went to Yale 3) The son went to Dartmouth.

Comment: Never mind, I got it

Comment: Read about markov chains: http://setosa.io/blog/2014/07/26/markov-chains/

Comment: About "never mind I got it" - you can post an answer to your own question. That's a good thing to do if you think someone else might learn from it, and you get good practice writing things down correctly. If you do, make the title more informative.

Comment: That was in reference to a comment made, which I edited. (the post I responded to was deleted). But I will post an answer as soon as I have it.